# Change "NOPMD" string for just a single rule

Tags: java, pmd

Is there any way to change the "NOPMD" string for just a single rule, while leaving it as "NOPMD" for all other rules during the same PMD run?  I know that the string can be changed globally for a single PMD run, but I just want it changed for just the one rule.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. If you can make a good case for this requirement, you might request a new feature from the PMD developers.